# In a dynamically generated table, I want to dynamically generate input tags, each with a unique id and an inline jQuery function, but it won't work.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

This isn't working:

My table is generated dynamically using PHP, so each row's edit button has a unique id, and a unique inline jQuery function. That jQuery function will load a jQuery modal dialog for the user to modify the row's data (triggering AJAX to update the database and reload a new tbody into the table with the updated data).

In practice, the button doesn't respond. I've put a simple alert into the function, but it also doesn't work.

(I'm using the $(#...).dialog('open') idiom elsewhere on the same page, and it works well.)

Here is the code:

```
<tr>
    <td>ADT Corporation Common Stock</td>
    <td>adt</td>
    <td>$31.59</td>
    <td>$-0.78</td>
    <td>-2.47%</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>FidelityIndividual</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>
        <script>
            $("#edit199").click(function(e){
                alert("in the <script> function");                 // doesn't work!
                //alert( $("input[name='editfields199']").val() ); // really doesn't work!
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#the_edit_form').dialog('open'); // should open a nice modal pop-up
            });    
        </script>
        // The edit icon that the user can click in order to edit that row/record.
        <input type="image" name="editfields199" id="edit199"    src="images/gtk_edit.png"    
            value="ADT Corporation Common Stock^adt^4^FidelityIndividual^199" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    ....more like the previous one...
<tr>
```

Comment: why you are attaching event to `id` instead of `class`?

Comment: Guruprasad Rao: because each row has unique data (for example, a database primary key), and if I use a class, only the first row is ever "recognized" by jQuery (in my experience).